# Inline editing with Laravel 5 and Bootstrap Editable: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, x-editable

I have a comment form and list on each post in my app, I just imported Bootstrap Editable to be able to give the users access to edit their comments inline without page reload.

But I keep getting this error

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
>
> POST http://localhost/r2/public/posts/comment/update 405 (Method Not Allowed)

I'm assuming it's something to do with my comment routes but I can't figure out what.

**EDIT:** After adding `type: 'post'` to `ajaxOptions` I started getting a different error

> Creating default object from empty value

It seems like `Input::get('commenter_comment')` is not returning anything. I guess this is wrong anyway as this is not the X-Editable field that is appearing.

How can I grab the X-Editable field?

Routes

```
Route::get('{post}/comment', ['as' => 'comment', 'uses' => 'CommentController@index']);
Route::post('{post}/post_this_comment', 'CommentController@post_this_comment');
Route::get('{post}/recaptcha', 'CommentController@recaptcha');
Route::get('{post}/reply_comment', 'CommentController@reply_comment');
Route::post('{post}/per_page', 'CommentController@per_page');
Route::post('{post}/comment/update', 'CommentController@update');
```

`Update()` method in `CommentController`

```
public function update() {
    $commentId = Input::get('pk');

    $newComment = Input::get('commenter_comment');

    $commentData = Comment::whereId($commentId)->first();

    $commentData->comment = $newComment;

    if($commentData->save())
        return Response::json(array('status'=>1));
    else
        return Response::json(array('status'=>0));
}
```

The View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $('.testedit').editable({
                validate: function(value) {
                    if($.trim(value) == '')
                        return 'Value is required.';
                },
                type: 'textarea',
                url: 'comment',
                title: 'Edit Comment',
                placement: 'top',
                send:'always',
                ajaxOptions: {
                    dataType: 'json'
                }
            });
        }
    );
</script>

<p><a href="#" class="testedit" pk="{{ $each_comment->id }}">{!! $each_comment->comment !!}</a></p>
```

Comment: try to fixed the missing closing curly brace in route
`Route::post('{post/comment/update', 'CommentController@update');`
to
`Route::post('{post}/comment/update', 'CommentController@update');` first

Comment: Fixed. sorry about that.

Comment: Set `post` type in `ajaxOptions`: `type: 'post'`

Comment: @manix that changed the error I was getting, now it's `Creating default object from empty value` so it seems `Input::get('commenter_comment')` is being returned empty. How can I catch what's in the X-Editable field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned, `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is thrown when you are using different HTTP verb. I mean, in you routes you declare the update route with `post` verb:

```
Route::post('{post}/comment/update', 'CommentController@update');
```

However, in you ajax options when type is not defined it do the request in GET, so you must to define it:

```
ajaxOptions: type: 'post'
```

Now, another error comes. You are not passing the post id expected in route's definition, that's why you are receiving an empty id, in consequence, a empty object is returned from database. So, you must to pass it as. But first, lets change the markup a little bit for each comment in order to set the the post's url via `data-url` and pk via `data-pk` attributes:

```
<a 
href="#" 
class="testedit" 
data-pk="{{ $each_comment->id }}"
data-url="{!! url($post->id . '/comment/update') !!}">
    {!! $each_comment->comment !!}
</a>
```

Now, `x-editable` will catch the `url` and `pk` values automatically without be set explicitly. Your final code should be close like this:

```
$(document).ready(
        function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $('.testedit').editable({
                validate: function(value) {
                    if($.trim(value) == '')
                        return 'Value is required.';
                },
                type: 'textarea',
                title: 'Edit Comment',
                placement: 'top',
                send:'always',
                ajaxOptions: {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post'
                }
            });
        }
    );
```

Don't forget that every argument defined in routes could be injected in controller's function. For example, your route is defining a `{post}` that expected to be the post id to edit:

```
Route::post('{post}/comment/update', 'CommentController@update');
```

So, in your `update()` just inject the argument:

```
public function update(Request $request, $post) {
    //$post has the Id of post to be edited

    // catching pk id:
    $pk = $request->get('pk');

    // catching the new comment
    $comment = $request->get('value');
```

Comment: For some reason I can't include `var post_id` inside `$('.testedit')` it gives a syntax error and if I put it outside, I get this `http://localhost/r2/public/posts/undefined/comment/update 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Actually I am trying to edit comments not posts. I don't know if this makes any difference here.

Comment: Well, passing the post is your definition, not mine haha. But relax, I understand what are you trying to achive. I will update my aswer

Comment: I had to pass the post when submitting a new comment because each comment is associated with a post, so I had to do it like that. But now when edit a comment, I don't think it's necessary. And thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This is great, it works mate :) But there is one small snag. The X-Editable field is adding padding to the comment with the underline decoration: http://i.imgur.com/Ba0fHd3.png anyway to remove this?

Comment: Nice, you could accept the answer if it fixed your original question. Regarding the padding issue, you could right click the padding in browser to find the CSS class and edit it in x-editable style-sheet

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is adding `pre-wrapped` class to it, once I remove it the extra space disappears. But how wise is it to do something like that? I don't think I'm supposed to alter how the plugin works, am I?

Comment: Do this cool trick. Overwrite that class attributes in another style-sheet. By this way you are respecting the plugin files and in the other hand you are customizing the style to your needs.

Comment: just did what you suggested, works great. Hope I didn't break anything though hehe... cheers man and thanks a lot.

Comment: `$post` actually is just an example representing the post object. Just replace it with your own

Comment: Sorry to bother you but it was a false alarm, I forgot that I can get the post id using `$each_comment->post_id` instead of using `$post`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of using xeditable with laravel

HTML

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/jqueryui-editable/css/jqueryui-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/jqueryui-editable/js/jqueryui-editable.min.js"></script> 

<div id="_token" class="hidden" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"></div>
<a href="#" id="industryName" data-type="text" data-pk="{{ $industry->id }}" data-title="Edit industry">{!! $industry->name !!}</a>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

       $.fn.editable.defaults.params = function (params) 
       {
        params._token = $("#_token").data("token");
        return params;
       };

     $('#industryName').editable({
                validate: function(value) {
                                            if($.trim(value) == '') 
                                                return 'Value is required.';
                                            },
                type: 'text',
                url:'/updateIndustry',   
                send:'always',
                ajaxOptions: {
                dataType: 'json'
                }

                } );
 } );
```

laravel route

```
Route::post('/updateIndustry',  'SettingsController@updateIndustry');
```

laravel controller

```
public function updatePosition(Request $request)
    {
        $id= $request->pk;
        $position = $request->value;

        $count = DB::table('designations')->whereRAW("position LIKE '%".$position."%'")->where('id','!=',$id)->count();
        if($count)
            echo "Similar position exists.";

        else
        {
            DB::table('designations')->where('id',$id)->update(['position' => $position]);
            echo "1";
        }
   }
```