# X-Editable cannot submit changes. Error Code 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4, x-editable

I'm facing problem in my Laravel project using bootstrap X-Editable.
whenever I want to submit my changes, it show error 405 (Method not allowed).
I've tried to change my route to PUT and POST method, but still got same error.
here's my piece of code

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = "inline";
  $.fn.editable.defaults.inputclass = "form-control input-sm";
  // $.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {type: "PUT"};
  // $.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {type: "POST"};

  $(".parts_qty").editable({
    type: "number",
    title: "Enter parts qty",
    send: "always",
    url: "/service/service-report/update-parts",
    params: function (params) {
      params._token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
      params.id = $(this).data("pk");
      params.qty = params.value;
      return params;
    },
    success: function (response, newValue) {
      if (response.success) {
        alert("Data changed successfully!");
      }
    },
    error: function (response, newValue) {
      alert("Woops Something wrong!");
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table-parts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Part Number</b></td>
            <td><b>Part Description</b></td>
            <td><b>Qty</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (SiteHelpers::get_recommendation_parts($data->id) as $part)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $part->part_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $part->part_description }}</td>
            <td data-name='qty'><a href="javascript:;" class="parts_qty" data-pk="{{ $part->id }}">{{ $part->parts_qty }}</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the error (can't upload as image).
[image: Error 405]

The error showed up when I click the Ok button :
[image: Input field]

Here's the route :

```html
Route::post('service/service-report/update-parts', 'Service\ServiceReportController@updateParts')->name('service-report/update-parts');
```

Comment: Try and add the route to the question as well that's where the error is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. thanks to similar post I found : [33284967](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284967/inline-editing-with-laravel-5-and-bootstrap-editable-405-method-not-allowed?rq=1)

This is what I did :

adding data-url to the input field.

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table-parts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Part Number</b></td>
            <td><b>Part Description</b></td>
            <td><b>Qty</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (SiteHelpers::get_recommendation_parts($data->id) as $part)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $part->part_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $part->part_description }}</td>
            <td data-name='qty'><a href="javascript:;" class="parts_qty" data-url="/service/service-report/update-parts/{{$part->id}}" data-pk="{{ $part->id }}">{{ $part->parts_qty }}</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

adding ajaxOptions to the javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$.fn.editable.defaults.inputclass = 'form-control input-sm';
    
    $('.parts_qty').editable({
        type: 'number',
        title: 'Enter parts qty',
        send: 'always',
        ajaxOptions: {
            type: 'post'
        },
        params: function(params) {
            params._token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            params.id = $(this).data('pk');
            params.qty = params.value;
            return params;
        },
        success: function(response, newValue) {
            if (response.success) {
                alert('Data changed succesfully!');
            }
        },
        error: function(response, newValue) {
            alert('Woops something wrong!');
        },
    });
});
```

adding ID to the route

```html
Route::post('service-report/update-parts/{id}', 'Service\ServiceReportController@updateParts')->name('service-report/update-parts');
```

Thank you stackoverflow!